# fluentd input everything that syslog has, before syslog starts

Tags: logging, fluentd, rsyslog

I have rsyslog on ubuntu configured to send everything to `fluentd`, and it works fine, but there are log messages in `/var/log/syslog` from before `syslog.service` starts and these log messages are not sent to `fluentd`.  Is there a way to get `fluentd` to pick up everything?  Specifically I am trying to pick up the kernel boot log (about 10 seconds worth) and items from cron's `@reboot`.  A simple cron job that works for `/var/log/syslog` but not `fluentd` would be `@reboot logger this does not get sent to fluentd`.

fluentd source config:

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 5140
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag system
</source>
```

rsyslog config has this added at the end:

```
*.* @127.0.0.1:5140
```

Comment: If you still haven't solved this, please share your configuration. I might have an idea what it could be.

Comment: @eDonkey what is your idea?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying; I meant the `rsyslog.conf`

Comment: @eDonkey it's the stock ubuntu config.  only one line is added

Comment: Alright, now i'm not quite sure if I understood you correctly, but are the boot messages logged and just not sent to fluentd? Or are they not being logged at all?

Comment: @eDonkey they are logged in `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: Oh alright, then I missunderstood. You might want to share all the "default files". Otherwise it's impossible to find out. I guess maybe something with your permissions is off, so the logs aren't pulled right from the *spool* directory.

Comment: @eDonkey you can find the "default file" in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rsyslog/rsyslog_8.2112.0-2ubuntu2.2.debian.tar.xz as debian/rsyslog.conf

Comment: First, I would check the permissions, then I would probably try delivering the logs over **TCP** instead of UDP e.g. `*.* @@127.0.0.1:5140` (double @). After that, If the error persists, you might see something in the logs which could help solve this.

Comment: @eDonkey check the permissions of what?  all other logs are working, after the rsyslog service starts.  i'll try tcp but since it's over localhost i can't image there is any loss due to udp.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought it's just an example Ip. But I think using TCP would be better anyways, as maybe fluentd takes more time to startup so that the logs get *dropped* due to UDP - instead TCP can then re-deliver the logs. Regarding the permissions i would check the rsyslogd (service) / spool dir permissions.